# Put the XFCE extended dektop on the right-side monitor

Tags: xorg, xfce, xrandr, multi-monitor

Is it possible to make an aoutput showing extended desktop to the left of the primary? I'm using xfce.

```
$ xrandr --output VGA1 --primary --right-of LVDS1
```

The above command makes VGA1 as extended desktop to the right of LVDS1 but the primary part of the desktop (the part showing the apps menu button, the desktops, apps instances, applets, time and date ...) is on LVDS1. I want it on VGA1.

Comment: In my opinion this is about xfce config and not directly xrandr. xrandr is not capable of doing such thing

Answer (score 2):

There is a [bug](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8328) in Xfce that always sets the left most monitor or the upper monitor to the primary monitor, if you reconfigure the monitors with `xrandr`.

So you have to either move the panels and etc by hand, or move the monitor to the right.

Comment: no, this does not work. The second command brings LVDS1 back on and to the left of VGA1, but it shows the the primary part of the desktop.

Comment: @user1850133 Oh ok, there is a bug in XFCE that sets the left and upper monitor to the primary monito. See https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8328